# Overstaying 90 day limit in Norway with long-term residence from EU country

Tags: schengen, eu

I'm a citizen of a third world country with long-term residence in EU country (Czech Republic). I'm currently spending some time in Norway, where I'm allowed to stay up to 90 days withing 180 days. But when I was buying return ticket I seem to have made a mistake in my calculations and I'm flying back on 97th day.

What are the chances of getting caught? Should I ditch the return ticket and buy an earlier one? (Do airlines pass flight information to local authorities, who follow every persons' ins and outs?)

Comment: How far away from the Swedish border are you?

Comment: Yes, I am, too, thinking about going to Sweden by bus and flying from there. :)

Comment: @Alexander and lewildintegral How would that make a difference?

Comment: If you take a one-week trip to Sweden, these seven days do not count towards the 90...

Comment: @Alexander Not true, both countries are part of the Schengen area.

Comment: The rule is 90 days in a 180-day period in the Schengen area but out of the Czech Republic, not 90 days in Norway or 90 days per country.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. I really thought it's per country.

Comment: @Relaxed are you sure about that? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @downhand I am pretty sure, yes. My reference would be article 5(1) and 5(1)(b) of the [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02006R0562-20131126). What other basis is there for either the right to be in another Schengen country at all or a 90-day limitation?

Comment: @Relaxed The Wikipedia citation for this fact is "Regulation (EU) No 265/2010 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 25 March 2010 amending the Convention Implementing the Schengen Agreement and Regulation (EC) No 562/2006 as regards movement of persons with a long-stay visa (OJ L 85, 31 March 2010, p. 1)"  Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_the_Schengen_Area#cite_note-187

Comment: @phoog I am looking at the consolidated versions, so that should already be in there. To make things even more complex, the convention has been “refactored” into the two regulations and is being phased out.

Comment: Also note that the text introduced by Regulation (EU) No 265/2010 has been further amended to get rid of the “three months in six months” (it's 90 days in 180 days now).

Comment: @lewildintegral I am not sure if it matters for visits to Norway, but what do you exactly mean with 'long-term residence'? You may have a 'long-term visa' (type D), a 'residence permit' or a 'permanent residence permit'. The difference between these titles are in some cases relevant when visiting other Schengen countries.

Comment: "Long-term residence" are the actual words I have written on my pink ID card I recieve every year in Czech Reoublic. It's not "permanent residence" and it's not a visa.

Answer (score 2):

No, airlines don't generally pass this information to the authorities. Some countries might still have more specific records but there is no general framework or legal basis to track people's movements within the Schengen area. It does however happen [in other situations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System), including for flights in and out of the Schengen area.

Very often, for internal Schengen flights, you don't have to provide anything else than your full name (i.e. no passport number, date of birth, etc.) which is not enough to uniquely identify you. A number of cross-border roads are also fully open. All this means the chances of getting caught are generally pretty low.

However, the lack of stamps or systematic controls does not mean it's absolutely impossible to be found out. Border checks do still occasionally take place and if all you have is a return ticket with 97 days between the two legs, there is a strong presumption that you overstayed, which could be enough to prompt further investigations.

Also, you mentioned in a comment that you regularly go to Norway. What you are doing there is none of my business but note that many people residing illegally in a country do get caught, not at the border or by a fancy database, but during some old-school police raid/inspection of their workplace. That's not relevant if you do not work but it's just one example of the way the rule is intended to work and how people get found out.

I know absolutely nothing about Norwegian procedural rules in this area but if it comes to it, entry/exit records are not the only type of evidence that could be used against you (think shopping receipts, student registration, phone contract…). If the presumption is strong enough it might even be up to you to prove you haven't stayed too long in the country by producing evidence of your travels or presence abroad (that's certainly how it works for short-stay visa holders who miss a stamp).

Comment: When I fly, they always ask me for my passport and my residence card, which contain all mentioned data. Which is more than enough in case they store it somewhere.

Comment: @lewildintegral It depends, flying where? With which airline?

Comment: Wizzair. I've been flying back and forth between Norway and Czech Republic over the last few months.

Comment: @lewildintegral Some airlines do, some airlines don't. I don't have any details about Wizzair and/or the Czech Republic, I just know there is no Schengen-wide system like that.